# Spawn an object next to another object with no instantiate

Tags: unity-game-engine, spawn

I have an object that is always in the same place and I want to spawn it next to another movable character. Or more specifically I have two, because is a turn based 3D game, I want to generate this object next to a character, and when the turn passes, spawn the same object next to another different character. The object would appear always next to mobile object at the beginning of his turn. For now I have this script inside the object:

```
    Vector3 initPosition //the position of the object that I want to move;
    private int whosTurn = 1;

    private IEnumerator WhoTurn()
    {
        if (whosTurn == 1)
        {
            GameController.MovePlayer(1);
            CameraController.isTurnPlayer1 = true;
            CameraController.isTurnPlayer2 = false;
            initPosition = positionPlayer1.transform.position;

        }
        else if (whosTurn == -1)
        {
            GameController.MovePlayer(2);
            CameraController.isTurnPlayer2 = true;
            CameraController.isTurnPlayer1 = false;
        }
        whosTurn = whosTurn * -1;
        yield return 0;
```

The thing is I don't want to use the instantiate method, just move the same object every turn, that's why I'm trying to change the 'InitPosition' from the Player character, but it' doesn't work. How can I do that?

Comment: Define "doesn't work." Because presently two things: 1) that value isn't used anywhere and 2) you never assign to it when `whosTurn == -1`

Comment: I tried to use "initPosition = positionPlayer1.transform.position" but it doesn't work, the object doesn't do what I want. I don't know what properties I should use to pass the value of a character's position on the object I want to move, and I don't want to be obligated to instantiate it.

Comment: And what is `initPosition`? This is a variable or field you've defined somewhere and in the code you've shown, it isn't used except that one line.

Comment: ah, well, "initPosition" is the start position of the object that I want to move. I have this code in the Start() function: "transform.position = initPosition", because the script is inside the game object I want to move. I just put the code of the corroutine that I use to change turns, because, I supposed, the line of code to change the object's position must be there.

Comment: `Start()` only runs once. If you want something to happen after that you need to put the code that does it somewhere else.

Comment: Only that code line is in Start(). The corroutine is in Update(). That code line of Start() it's just to initialize the object in a certain place, but, frankly, I do not know if it's really necessary, but in any case, my doubt is not that. My question is how to move this object to the position of another object. I don't know how to write it in a code, that's why I'm here. I was looking for an idea of how would another more experienced person do it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
public Transform pObject;//(player object)
public Transform eObject;//(enemy object)
```

void Awake(){
here you need to assign BOTH objects initial positions, by both objects i mean the two items you want to spawn them next too. im not sure how youre assigning this, but since 
im using public variables, you can just drag both the objects into the this script in the inspector, but if you are using tags, you will grab them in :

```
void Awake(){
}
```

then you can just do this:

```
 private IEnumerator WhoTurn()
    {
        if (whosTurn == 1)
        {
            GameController.MovePlayer(1);
            CameraController.isTurnPlayer1 = true;
            CameraController.isTurnPlayer2 = false;
           transform.position=pObject.position;
    }
    else if (whosTurn == -1)
    {
        GameController.MovePlayer(2);
        CameraController.isTurnPlayer2 = true;
        CameraController.isTurnPlayer1 = false;
        transform.position=eObject.position;
    }
    whosTurn = whosTurn * -1;
    yield return 0;
```

so you're going to need a variable for both locations, then you can just switch back and forth. this script will work on the object you want to move.

alternatively, i know you dont want to use instantiation, but you could just instantiate one item when a players turn starts, then `Destroy(gameObject)` when there turn ends.